# CollectionView bounds

Tags: ios

Is it possible to make a view in a section header come out of the `CollectionView` bounds?

I'm trying to place a view inside the `CollectionView` header that should go out of the `CollectionView` bounds a bit by setting the `clipsToBounds` property to `NO` on both the header view and the `CollectionView`, but that doesn't seem to have any effect. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you also setting `clipsToBounds` to `NO` on the collection view?

Comment: Yes, on both the CollectionView and the UICollectionReusableView (the header)